# Fast DCT code in C

Tags: fourier-transform

I wrote this code in c for fast DCT (type II) of 8 values:
https://anotepad.com/note/read/99kdhg

The method works, but is this as fast as other existing algorithms, or are there any faster ways?
The goal is to be as fast and efficient as possible (CPU wise)

(first function is ran once to fill the constants array (c) and the 2nd function does the fast dct for 8 values n=input o=output)

Thanks

Comment: DCT can benefit from FFT like factorizations, but for as few as 8 values I don't know how much it helps. It probably depends a lot on the use cases and setup of the machine you want to run it for.

Comment: For performance on desktop CPUs (and even more so on server CPUs) lots will be gained by arranging the calculations to maximize the vectorization capabilities, SIMD instructions and so on. But c is coded for lots of other different platforms and hardwares than the ones which have good vectorization.

Comment: there is no need of multiplying by $c[8]$ every time, precalculate this directly in $c[0],...c[6]$ coefficients.

Comment: Now for most compilers that have vectorial capabilities defining local variables $q_i$ like this will kill the vectorization. Just write the $n[i]$ directly in the formulas and you can benefit from auto-vectoring in most cases, but this is not really a mathematical subject any more...

Comment: Am I the only one not knowing what "DCT" is ?

Comment: @Peter: DCT = [Discrete Cosine Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform)

Comment: @zwim Thank you. This is helpful. This is the new version (also including the inverse DCT):
https://anotepad.com/note/read/sqa9xk
q variables are pre defined as an array. All constants are multiplied by c[8] in the initialization method